# Multiple attachments

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want to use php mailer for sending multiple attachment in mail.
But the problem is, how to use it. Where to download it, how to install it,. I have searched for 3 days, but have got confused, two or three tutorials that i used, doesn't work and make me more confused.
I want a single file tag, that uploads multiple attachments , and send them in email.
I have done with the Email sending with one attachment successfully..

Please guide me. And please give those links that really work for the purpose.

Comment: Use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead.

Comment: okk. any tutorial that really works, that guide me

Comment: See the documentation. http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction.html

Comment: The documentation I linked to contains examples, just open your eyes and look, e.g. [here](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#attaching-files) We are here to help with specific questions, not to spoon-feed every step to you. If that's what you're looking for consider taking a course or hiring a coach.

Comment: Sorry. I was confused so i said that.

Comment: no problem, my response was louder than I intended as well :) Check out either Treffynnon's answer, or the SwiftMailer example page. Both ways should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) can be [downloaded](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/PHPMailer%20v5.1/PHPMailer_v5.1.zip/download) from [its SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/PHPMailer%20v5.1/).

Now to the code, which is mostly taken from the examples provided in the ZIPball:

```
<?php
require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); //defaults to using php "mail()"; the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

try {
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
  $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK</p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
?>
```

Comment: PHPMailer is a bit of a mess - there are at least two different versions around, with incompatible variable names and functions.  That's why I tend to recommend Swiftmailer.

Comment: The sourceforge URL above hasn't changed from when I started to use it 7 years ago or so. I notice that worxware are trying to move to google code since I last looked - what a mess! (as you say) I like SwiftMailer too and use it extensively, but he asked for PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of multiple scripts and a bit of reading. I haven't added any form processing or the like, but it allows for the use of the  option to attach multiple files through one input button. Hope its helpful to someone. I'm sure it breaks all kinds of standards. I do know it works in Chrome 31 and IE10.

Edit: Working with this little script, I added HTML formatting for the message and the thank you message replacement.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

    $email_to = "";
    $email_subject = "";
    $thankyou = "thanks.html";

    // boundary
    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    function died($error) {
        echo "Sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    $requester_name = $_POST['requester_name']; // required
    $requester_email = $_POST['requester_email']; // required




    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message = "<html><body> \r\n";
    $email_message .= "<table style=\"border: 1px #777 solid; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px;\" cellpadding=\"7\"> \r\n";
    $email_message .= "<tr><td style=\"background: #444; color:#fff;\"><strong>New Hire Form</strong></td><td style=\"background: #444; color:#fff;\">Requirements</td></tr>" . "\n";

    $email_message .= "<tr><td style=\"background: #ccc;\"><strong>Requester Name: </strong></td><td style=\"background: #ddd;\">" .clean_string($requester_name). "</td></tr>" . "\n";
    $email_message .= "<tr><td style=\"background: #ccc;\"><strong>Requester Email: </strong></td><td style=\"background: #ddd;\">".clean_string($requester_email). "</td></tr>" . "\n";



    $email_message .= "</table> \r\n";
    $email_message .= "</body></html>";


    // multipart boundary
$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $email_message . "\n\n";



for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['attachfile']['name']);$i++)  
{  

  if($_FILES['attachfile']['name'][$i] != "")  
  {  
    //here you will get all files selected by user.




      $name = ($_FILES['attachfile']['name'][$i]);
      $tmp_name = ($_FILES['attachfile']['tmp_name'][$i]);
      $type = ($_FILES['attachfile']['type'][$i]);
      $size = ($_FILES['attachfile']['size'][$i]);

    echo count($_Files['attachfile']) ;
    echo $_FILES['attachfile']['name'][$i] ;
    echo $_FILES['attachfile']['tmp_name'][$i] ;
    echo $_FILES['attachfile']['type'][$i] ;


            // Read the file content into a variable
            $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');
            $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));
            // Close the file
            fclose($file);


            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));


         $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
            " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
            " filename=\"{$name}\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
         $data . "\n\n";
  }
}

    $headers .= 'From: '.$email_sender."\r\n".   // Mail will be sent from your Admin ID
    'Reply-To: '.$Email."\r\n" .                // Reply to Sender Email
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
// headers for attachment
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);


?>

<script>location.replace('<?php echo $thankyou;?>')</script>
<?php
}
die();
?>
```